# Отобразить данные из двух таблиц

Tags: php, sql

Есть две таблицы sql:
Одна с заказами, а  другая со статусами заказов:

1. первая таблица:

```
|id|id_status|
|1 |1        |
|2 |2        |
|3 |3        |
```

2. Вторая таблица:

```
 |id_status|status  |
 |1        |Ожидание| 
 |1        |Ожидание| 
 |2        |Готов   | 
 |2        |Готов   | 
 |3        |Отменен |
```

Я делаю это так:

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password', 'namedb');
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON id=1 ");
    $results = array();
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)) {
    echo $result['status']; }
```

Я хочу получить имя статуса Ожидание если в первой таблице id = 1, но вместо корректного результата у меня фигня выходит(

Comment: Запрос кривой потому что. Надо связать таблицы не по условию отбора, а по условию связывания, и дополнительно сделать отбор в секции отбора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте запрос таким образом, если вы хотите только для id=1

```
SELECT `table2`.`status` as `status`
  FROM `table1` 
     LEFT JOIN `table2`
     using(`id_status`) 
  WHERE `table1.id` = 1
```

или так, если для всех

```
SELECT `table1`.`id` as `id`, `table2`.`status` as `status`
  FROM `table1` 
     LEFT JOIN `table2`
     using(`id_status`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Неверный синтаксис запроса

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.status 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id_status=table2.id_status
```

Comment: В table2 нет поля id.